# How do I set a delay for an animation to finish before loading the next page? [jQuery, Bootstrap]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

jQuery:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.menuElements').hover(
            function(){             
                $(this).addClass('animated bounce');
            },
            function(){
                $(this).removeClass('animated bounce');
        });

        //trying to create delay here
        $('.menuElements').click(
            function(){
                $(this).addClass('slideOutUp').delay(1000);
            }
        )
    });
```

html:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div class='container-fluid col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 menuContainer'>
        <div class='row-fluid' style='height:100%'>
            <a href='#'>
            <div id='home' class='container col-xs-3 menuElements' style='background-color: #C22326'>
                <img class='myIcons center-block vertical-align' src='images/home.png'>
            </div>
            </a>
            <a href='#'>
            <div id='projects' class='container col-xs-3 menuElements' style='background-color: #F37338'>
                <img class='myIcons center-block vertical-align' src='images/projects.png'>
            </div>
            </a>
            <a href='#'>
            <div id='aboutMe' class='container col-xs-3 menuElements' style='background-color: #FDB632'>
                <img class='myIcons center-block vertical-align' src='images/aboutMe.png'>
            </div>
            </a>
            <a href='#'>
            <div id='contactMe' class='container col-xs-3 menuElements' style='background-color: #027878'>
                <img class='myIcons center-block vertical-align' src='images/contactMe.png'>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What my page looks like are four columns and when I click on a column it slides up and loads the next page (which I still need to configure the href). **What I'm trying to do is have the column slide up on click and finish the animation before loading the new page.**

I'm fairly new to jQuery and trying to teach myself so if you know any good resources, besides http://api.jquery.com/, I can use that would be great!

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a delay.

Either set a [delay in the animation](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) itself:

`$(".menuElements").addClass("slideOutUp").delay(HOW_LONG);`

Or you could [set a timeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) before continuing to the next action with JS:

`setTimeout(function(){ $(".menuElements").addClass("slideOutUp") }, HOW_LONG);`

Answer (score 0):

$(".menuElements").addClass("slideOutUp").delay(1000);

Answer (score 0):

You can use timeout to delay the animation. For Example

```
window.setTimeout(function(){

$(".menuElements").addClass('slideOutUp');

}, 1000);
```